# Full Screen Control in the map

Tags: here-api

Is there a Fullscreen control like in Gmaps? I have read the docs but did not found anything?

Even it's important for the mobiles.

Comment: What do you mean by "fullscreen control" ?

Comment: an API does not have a screen.

Comment: The fullscreen map control is added by default in GoogleMaps.  MapBox enables the controll via `map.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl());`... I've been looking for the same thing with HERE and can't find it referenced in their documentation.  Leaflet.js works w/HERE and offers a fullscreen control... maybe that's an acceptable workaround? https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.fullscreen

Comment: We added a "HERE" map to our contact page and it's very small in mobile with no way to easily expand or go into full screen mode like Google Maps & MapBox.  This seems like a missing feature and it isn't referenced anywhere in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the HERE JavaScript SDK, then you will have to set the size of the map div to the size of your fullscreen (the map will always take the size of its containing div).

See examples here:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js

If you are using HERE mobile SDKs,then the map is by default rendered in full screen.